NextJS Server Component Data Mutation
'use server';
import TirestockComponent from '@components/TirestockComponent';
import { fetchTirestock } from '@nextapi/fetchTirestock';

export default async function UsedTirestock() {
  const condition = 'used';
  const fetchedTirestock = await fetchTirestock(condition);
  return (
    <TirestockComponent
      condition={condition}
      fetchedTirestock={fetchedTirestock}
    />
  );
}


I have a server side component that fetches a list of objects. which object has a tire size how many singles sets and pairs etc.
Inside the TirestockComponent i change some values of some objects. this is sent to api which handles the change. i optimistcly change "context' or the fetchedTirestock.
When i switch to another page and come back to the this page ^^ i see the not optimistcly changed version / the original unchanged fetchTirestock. this is because fetchTirestock is cached by nextjs which is good to avoid refetchs. i want to update that cache to the optimistcly changed version without having to refetch a whole list for 1 changed object.
I have tried react query

export default function UsedComponent({ condition, fetchedTirestock }) {
  const { data: Tirestock = [] } = useQuery(`${condition}tirestock`, {
    initialData: fetchedTirestock,
  });


but upon reloading i get a mismatch error. and also i have a queryFn error which is due to not setting the queryFn but if i do set the queryFn the useQuery will send a fetch request for tirestock on mount even thought there is the fetchedTirestock passed in from the SSR making SSR pointless. without using queryFn and ignoring the error after changing an object and reloading page i get a mismatch error from nextjs indicating the React rendered is different from server rendered data
